# Vue.js b-table slots not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

My Vue-bootstrap table is not rendering slots correctly.

If I copy the examples of the [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/) website to my Vue application, the slots are not rendered. The application compiles without errors.
Some slots (e.g. table-busy) works correctly, but others don't

```
<template>
<b-table
  :fields="tableHeaders"
  :items="tableRows"
  :busy="!tableLoaded"
>
  <template v-slot:cell()="data">
    <i>{{ data.value }}</i>
  </template>
</b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    tableHeaders: [
      {
        key: 'Employee',
        stickyColumn: true,
        isRowHeader: true,
        variant: 'primary',
      }, 
      'Status'
    ],
    tableRows: [
      Employee: 'Emp 1', status: 'Active',
      Employee: 'Emp 2', status: 'Active',
    ]
}
</script>
```

Data values are not shown in italic font style. The compiler doesn't show any errors. Does anyone know how this can be solved?

Comment: Ensure you are using the latest version of BootstrapVue `2.0.4`.  The `2.0.0-rc##` releases used a different naming syntax for the table cell slots. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/misc/changelog#migration-guide-v200